# Trying to extend a Vuetify component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

I would like to make ready to use components with my classes/stylish, I'm using mixins for the thing, but it seams the properties are not passed. I get the style but not the "items" i.e.

This is the code:

```
<template>
  <span>
    <p
      class="text-left text-secondary text-caption ml-2 pb-0 pt-0 mb-0 mt-0"
      v-if="label"
    >
      {{ label }}
    </p>
    <v-autocomplete
      :class="getClass"
      outlined
      single-line
      hide-details
      v-bind="$props"
    />
  </span>
</template>

<script>
import { VAutocomplete } from "vuetify/lib";

export default {
  mixins: [VAutocomplete],

  data() {
    return {};
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$props);
  },

  watch: {},

  computed: {
    getClass() {
      return "input-style font-size-input text-light-input placeholder-light border-radius-md select-style mt-0 mb-2";
    },
  },

  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

Comment: I take it this is veujs2 not 3

Comment: yes it's vue.js 2 and this should be doable

Comment: You're right. It should be doable. What are the "items" you refer to

Comment: just an example, the :items property pass to the v-autocomplete item the list of the items in the submenu.it is ignored at the moment, so not everything is passed along the child component